# Using IFolderView::GetSortColumns in C# to sort items in folder

Tags: c#, c++, sorting, winapi, windows-explorer

I am currently trying to programmatically sort a folder from the Windows Explorer in C#. But strangely, I keep hitting a "System.AccessViolationException".

My code is the following:

Program.cs:

```
WinAPI.SORTCOLUMN test = new WinAPI.SORTCOLUMN();
//At this point it is assumed that a shellView-Object of the correct windows explorer window is beeing casted to type folderView2 of type IFolderView2
folderView2.GetSortColumns(ref test, columnCount); //System.AccessViolationException hits. What to do?
```

WinAPI.cs:

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("cde725b0-ccc9-4519-917e-325d72fab4ce")]
public interface IFolderView
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetCurrentViewMode(ref FOLDERVIEWMODE pViewMode);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetCurrentViewMode(FOLDERVIEWMODE ViewMode);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetFolder(ref Guid riid, out IPersistFolder2 ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Item(int iItemIndex, out IntPtr ppidl);

    [PreserveSig]
    int ItemCount(uint uFlags, out int pcItems);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Items(uint uFlags, [In] ref Guid riid, out object ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSelectionMarkedItem(out int piItem);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetFocusedItem(out int piItem);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetItemPosition(IntPtr pidl, out POINT ppt);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSpacing(ref POINT ppt);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDefaultSpacing(ref POINT ppt);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetAutoArrange();

    [PreserveSig]
    int SelectItem(int iItem, int dwFlags);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SelectAndPositionItems(uint cidl, IntPtr apidl, IntPtr apt, int dwFlags);
}

//https://github.com/shellscape/Shellscape.Common/blob/aa5465929e842e4bcc88c29c1cc369122c307bc6/Microsoft/Windows%20API/Shell/Interop/ExplorerBrowser/ExplorerBrowserCOMInterfaces.cs
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("1af3a467-214f-4298-908e-06b03e0b39f9")]
public interface IFolderView2 : IFolderView
{
    [PreserveSig]
    void GetSortColumnCount(ref int pcColumns);
    [PreserveSig]
    void GetSortColumns(ref SORTCOLUMN rgSortColumns, int cColumns);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SORTCOLUMN
{
    public PROPERTYKEY propkey;
    public string direction;

    public SORTCOLUMN(PROPERTYKEY propkey, string direction)
    {
        this.propkey = propkey;
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROPERTYKEY
{
    public Guid fmtid;
    public string pid;

    public PROPERTYKEY(Guid fmtid, string pid)
    {
        this.fmtid = fmtid;
        this.pid = pid;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing an array of size 1, but request `columnCount` items to be written to it. I'd slap you with a large trout for that. The system is less emotional, and throws an access violation at you instead.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sorry, I can't really follow you there... How would I solve this then?

Comment: By passing an array of size `columnCount`, or by requesting a single item only.

Comment: So something along the lines of WinAPI.SORTCOLUMN[] test = new WinAPI.SORTCOLUMN[columnCount];
folderView2.GetSortColumns(ref test, columnCount); should do the trick?

Comment: Also, I am sorry to have "annoyed" you like this, but I have literally not found any documentation for this function, or IFolderView2 in general

Comment: There are massive amounts of documentation for COM, e.g. [IFolderView2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775541.aspx) or [IFolderView2::GetSortColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775533.aspx). You just don't know, how to translate that to your preferred development platform. I cannot help you with that, as I don't like or do much .NET development.

Comment: That's true, I usually rely on PInvoke.net and not translate those things myself, but it seems like I have to get into that sort of programming myself as well. Thanks for your help tough, I will try to solve this problem on Monday with your help.

Comment: @IInspectable - Passing an array to GetSortColumns causes me to get a InvalidArgument Exception. My example also passed an object of type SORTCOLUMN and not an array of length 1

Comment: @StefanC: There are several ready-made solutions for your problem, for example [ShellBrowser Components .NET Edition](http://www.jam-software.com/shellbrowser_net/) by JAM Software. Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of the ShellBrowser Delphi edition.